# Various R data storage options for key value pairs: Pros and Cons

Tags: r

I am often confused about which of the following style of data objects to use in practical problems:

List:

```
person_list<-list(age=25,weight=180,height=150,male=TRUE,profession="doctor")
```

Array:

```
person_array<-c(age=25,weight=180,height=150,male=TRUE,profession="doctor")
```

Hash:

```
person_hash<-hash(age=25,weight=180,height=150,male=TRUE,profession="doctor")
```

Data Frame:

```
person_frame<-data.frame(attributes=c("age","weight","height","male","profession"),values=c(25,180,150,TRUE,"doctor"))
```

In hindsight, the data frame choice seems silly but what about the others? Are they all OK?

Or is there an advantage / disadvantage of using one form over another?

e.g. Since hash isn't native data type R Studio won't autocomplete it so that's a minor disadvantage. Any other such issues?

PS. The data isn't huge. So performance isn't a major concern. Ease of coding is and likelihood of mistakes / bugs etc. is.

Answer (score 1):

Collect my comments

In your variants (without hash) only `List` is good enougth.

1) Array - good for one class because all converted to more wide one ( `character` here)

2)Data.farme - good , but when you  create it in this way ( used `c`) it became bad

3) List -most flexible one

## Example

data

```
person_array<-c(age=25,weight=180,height=150,male=TRUE,profession="doctor")
person_list<-list(age=25,weight=180,height=150,male=TRUE,profession="doctor")
person_frame<-data.frame(attributes=c("age","weight","height","male","profession"),values=c(25,180,150,TRUE,"doctor"))
person_frame_good<-data.frame(age=25,weight=180,height=150,male=TRUE,profession="doctor")
```

operations

```
> person_array$height+person_array$weight
Error in person_array$height : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> person_array[["height"]]+person_array[["weight"]]
Error in person_array[["height"]] + person_array[["weight"]] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
> person_frame$height+person_frame$weight
numeric(0)
> person_frame$values[person_frame$attributes=="height"]+person_frame$values[person_frame$attributes=="weight"]
[1] NA
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(person_frame$values[person_frame$attributes == "height"],  :
  ‘+’ не значимо для факторов
> person_list$height+person_list$weight
[1] 330
> person_frame_good$height+person_frame_good$weight
[1] 330
```

So you can see that only `list` and df_good can sum var

PS "‘+’ не значимо для факторов" means something like "+ cant be used for factors"

## Bonus

If you are using RStudio you can simply see your data in 
`data.frame`
[image]

but `list` cant
[image]

but `View` commands works good in both variants( if data can be presented in two way table)